# what is the difference between hanoten layaef koach and hamaavir sheina meeinai

Tags: tefilla

What is the difference in the meaning of the blessings hanoten layaef koach and hamaavir sheina meeinai? They both looks like they refer that the person isn't tired now?

Comment: Why does there need to be a difference?

Comment: if there wouldn't be a difference we wouldn't do two brachot. One should be a more comprehensive bracha. ?For example if one blessed zokef kfufim before matir asurim, he doesn't say matir asurim again.

Comment: Why wouldn't we do two brachot? Hanotein Layaeif isn't in the Gemara so I don't why you assume there's consistent thought behind it and not just extra praises

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95
ואם בירך תחילה זוקף כפופים קאמר רב עמרם שלא יברך אחר כך מתיר אסורים, שלפי שבכלל זקיפת הקומה היא תנועת האברים, ולמה יחזור לברך פעם שנית על זה?

Comment: @DoubleAA but there should be a reason why it was added in  a later stage and hamaavir sheina was not enough?

Comment: See here: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&st=&pgnum=115

Answer (score 2):

Rav Avraham Landau, in Siddur Tzelosa Deavraham (to this Beracha, [page 115](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&st=&pgnum=115), thanks to user17212), suggests that Hanosein Layaef Koach refers to extra strength given to us when we wake up, not simply that we are no longer tired (which is presumably what the Beracha of Hamaavir Sheina thanks Hashem for).

Comment: I've never noticed having parituclarly more strength immediately upon waking.

Comment: @DoubleAA you don't feel stronger (more refreshed) when you wake up than when you go to sleep?

Comment: I feel less tired. On rare occasions even Zero tired. You seemed to be saying there's more than that.

Comment: @DoubleAA There's tired, and there's stronger.  I feel like you can make a Chiluk between them sometimes.

Comment: But then doesn't this make the bracha of hamaavir Shena unnecessary?

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang it would seem that way, unless we feel that they are two completely separate praiseworthy things.  If you had a new renewed strength, but were still tired, would you be happy?  But I think the question is better than the answer.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang either which way, Hamaavir Sheina was there before, and Hanosein Layaef was added for Kabbalistic reasons that I don't know.